# Neo4j doesnot start after the load database command

Tags: neo4j, load, dump

I am working on neo4j community edition. I tried to create the backup of database using the load and dump command. They got successfully executed and the backup of the database has been created . But after the load command the neo4j Browser stopped working what should i do?

Comment: There can be any number of reasons why the neo4j Browser would not work as expected. For us to help you, you need to provide a reasonably detailed explanation of what you mean by  "stopped working".

Comment: The neo4j browser window refused to connect to localhost. Later on after using purge neo4j and then reinstalling the database the graph was reloaded.Is it the right way to do the load dump operation. I am posting the video of operation i performed.Kindly Have a look

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ljBn2T9qRevlZCWvGzwDCOzo_fGqhBdd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It should not be necessary to reinstall neo4j. What happens if you just restart neo4j right after the loading?

Comment: Nothing happens.localhost:7474 refused to connect

Answer (score 1):

I am having an identical experience (though I am trying to connect even outside of localhost), and a purge and reinstall will work, though it doesn't erase the loaded database itself.

To fill in some of the details of the problem, as I experienced it.

1. I stop Neo4j desktop on Windows. I dump the database by navigating to the database folder / bin.
2. I run this: `neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=c:\`
3. I installed Neo4j on a remote server, open it to the world, and the Neo4j browser is able to run.
4. I copy the dump to the remote server. I stop neo4j by running: `systemctl stop neo4j`
5. I load the database by running: `neo4j-admin load --from=./graph.db.dump --database=graph.db --force`
6. I try starting the database by typing `systemctl start neo4j`
7. The Neo4j browser doesn't load. I give it several minutes, still doesn't load.
8. I try starting the database by typing `systemctl restart neo4j`
9. The Neo4j browser doesn't load. I give it several minutes, still doesn't load.

My solution, which finally worked:

1. `sudo apt-get purge neo4j*`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. `sudo apt-get install neo4j-enterprise=1:3.5.6`
4. Re-edit any config files, for instance, to open to the world.
5. `systemctl start neo4j`
6. `systemctl restart neo4j`

Load it in the web browser. The Neo4j browser works, and the database has been loaded.

Maybe there is a more straightforward way to figure out what file has been clobbered by the load operation, but so far, no one else has answered, and this one certainly works.

Comment: This should be marked with the correct answer.  If you are using version 4+ this is not an issue but as you cannot load 3.0 dump into a 4.0 database you have to upgrade in place many using the community edition are still on 3.0 versions.